# Twilio Android Programmable voice SDK does not receive Push notification when the phone goes in Doze mode

Tags: android, push-notification, twilio, voip

I have implemented VOIP calling in my app using Twilio voice sdk, as explained here.. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/android/getting-started

The app receives the push notification and then the call. However, when I leave the phone for a while or manually kick in the Android Doze mode, the push notification is not received and thus the call is also not received.

As per this http://www.howtogeek.com/242563/how-androids-doze-improves-your-battery-life-and-how-to-tweak-it/ , Twilio must send a high priority push notification but that seems not the case.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: If you look closely in their code, you can set priority of the notification itself. Look for classes under the gcm folder. Notification builder is used to build the notification - just set the priority there only.